# R Programming: sample() function return repeated entities even replace=TRUE

Tags: r, sampling

I am using sample() function to obtain a random sample from a dice object.

```
> die
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
> sample(x=die , size=1 , replace=TRUE)
[1] 1
> sample(x=die , size=1 , replace=TRUE)
[1] 1
> sample(x=die , size=1 , replace=TRUE)
[1] 5
> sample(x=die , size=1 , replace=TRUE)
[1] 5
> sample(x=die , size=1 , replace=TRUE)
[1] 1
> sample(x=die , size=1 , replace=TRUE)
[1] 2
> sample(x=die , size=1 , replace=TRUE)
[1] 4
```

If you observe above output 1 repeated 3 times and 5 repeated 2 times. But from above output even replace TRUE I could see frequent multiple duplications.

Ref: I am reading a book named **Hands-On Programming with R**.

Please let me know if more information required.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a statistical, but a programming question and would be better suited for Stack Overflow.

You are using `sample()` incorrectly if your goal is to avoid getting the same number twice. To avoid repetitions, you need to create the sample with a single command (`size` more than 1 instead of multiple commands) and using `replace=FALSE` (not `TRUE`). For example:

```
> sample(x=die , size=4 , replace=FALSE)
[1] 1 6 4 3
```

Of course, this no longer corresponds to multiple fair dice rolls, as real dice can give you the same number in subsequent rolls.

See the help page `?sample` for full information on how to use `sample()`.

Answer (score 3):

If you take real dice and roll them, you will see duplications as well. Each side of the dice has the same chance to come up each time, no matter if that means duplication or not.

The `replace=` argument has no effect at all, when `size=1`, as after you have drawn one side of the dice, it makes no difference, whether you replace that or not. `replace=FALSE` will prevent duplicates whithin that one call of `sample()`. It will not influence the next call of `sample`.

Comment: And whether by co-incidence or not he did it 7 times which with a six-sided die ............

Answer (score 1):

Sample() doesn't affect subsequent runs of sample() on the same vector. What you need is a function that progressively removes your pics from the vector you are analyzing. Here I wrote something like it, called rsample(), which returns the object taken and the new vector, deprived of the selected object.

```
rsample<-function(x){
    taken<-sample(x,size=1)
    newx<-x[-which(x==taken)[1]]
    return(list(taken=taken,new=newx))
}
die<-1:6
obj<-rsample(die)
obj$taken
[1] 3
obj<-rsample(obj$new)
obj$taken
[1] 5
obj<-rsample(obj$new)
obj$taken
[1] 2
obj<-rsample(obj$new)
obj$taken
[1] 4
obj<-rsample(obj$new)
obj$taken
[1] 1
```

Comment: May be we can use this to avoid duplicate elements in a 1-D vector data along with sample() function as vector length as conditional value.

Comment: No , 1-D+Sample() but no duplicate repetitions till vector length samplings. Hope you understand.

Comment: @Raja Isn't that much more simply achieved with `replicate = FALSE`?

Comment: @Raja `sample(1:n, size=n, replace=FALSE)` will never have repetitions in the returned values.

Comment: Federico Giorgi's function will allow you to call that function a number of times but it is probably much faster to once call `sample` than to repeatedly call Federico Giorgi's `rsample`. It may in rare cases be better to use this, but usually: Just take a large `sample` and use it up bit by bit.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simply far easier to call `sample(die, 6, replace = FALSE)`?